# C# Constructor constratint to types that support comparison operators

Tags: c#

How do I create a class to store a range of any type provided that the type allows comparison operators to ensure that that the first value provided to the constructor is less than the second?

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private readonly T lowerBound;
    private readonly T upperBound;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Range class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lowerBound">The smaller number in the Range tuplet</param>
    /// <param name="upperBound">The larger number in the Range tuplet</param>
    public Range(T lowerBound, T upperBound)
    {
        if (lowerBound > upperBound)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("lowerBlound must be less than upper bound", lowerBound.ToString());
        }

        this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
        this.upperBound = upperBound;            
    }
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error   1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'  C:\Source\MLR_Rebates\DotNet\Load_MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO\Load_MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO\Range.cs   27  17  Load_MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine two suggestions already given, we combine the ability to create Ranges with a manually defined comparison rule, with an over-ride for those types that implement `IComparable<T>`, and with compile-time safety on the latter.

We take much the same approach as the static `Tuple` class' `Create` method. This can also offer concision in allowing us to rely upon type inference:

```
public static class Range // just a class to a hold the factory methods
{
    public static Range<T> Create<T>(T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return new Range<T>(lower, upper, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }
    //We don't need this override, but it adds consistency that we can always
    //use Range.Create to create a range we want.
    public static Range<T> Create<T>(T lower, T upper, IComparer<T> cmp)
    {
        return new Range<T>(lower, upper, cmp);
    }
}
public class Range<T>
{
    private readonly T lowerBound;
    private readonly T upperBound;
    private readonly IComparer<T> _cmp;
    public Range(T lower, T upper, IComparer<T> cmp)
    {
        if(lower == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lower");
        if(upper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("upper");
        if((_cmp = cmp).Compare(lower, upper) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Argument \"lower\" cannot be greater than \"upper\".");
        lowerBound = lower;
        upperBound = upper;
    }
}
```

Now we can't accidentally construct a `Range` with the default comparer where it won't work, but can also leave out the comparer and have it compile only if it'll work.

Edit:

There are two main approaches to having items comparable in an order-giving way in .NET and this uses both.

One way is to have a type define its on way of being compared with another object of the same type*. This is done by `IComparable<T>` (or the non-generic `IComparable`, but then you have to catch type mis-matches at run-time, so it isn't as useful post .NET1.1).

`int` for example, implements `IComparable<int>`, which means we can do `3.CompareTo(5)` and receive a negative number indicating that 3 comes before 5 when the two are put into order.

Another way is to have an object that implements `IComparer<T>` (and likewise a non-generic `IComparer` that is less useful post .NET1.1). This is used to compare two objects, generally of a **different** type to the comparer. We explicitly use this either because a type we are interested in doesn't implement `IComparable<T>` or because we want to override the default sorting order. For example we could create the following class:

```
public class EvenFirst : IComparer<int>
{
  public int Compare(int x, int y)
  {
    int evenOddCmp = x % 2 - y % 2;
    if(evenOddCmp != 0)
      return evenOddCmp;
    return x.CompareTo(y);
  }
}
```

If we used this to sort a list of integers (`list.Sort(new EvenFirst())`), it would put all the even numbers first, and all the odd numbers last, but have the even and odd numbers in normal order within their block.

Okay, so now we've got two different ways of comparing instances of a given type, one which is provided by the type itself and which is generally the "most natural", which is great, and one which gives us more flexibility, which is also great. But this means that we will have to write two versions of any piece of code that cares about such comparisons - one that uses `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` and one that uses `IComparer<T>.Compare()`.

It gets worse if we care about two types of objects. Then we need 4 different methods!

The solution is provided by `Comparer<T>.Default`. This static property gives us an implementation of `IComparer<T>.Compare()` for a given `T` that calls into `IComparable<T>.CompareTo`.

So, now we generally only ever write our methods to make use of `IComparer<T>.Compare()`. Providing a version that uses `CompareTo` for the most common sort of comparisons is just a matter of an override that uses the default comparer. E.g. instead of:

```
public void SortStrings(IComparer<string> cmp)//lets caller decide about case-sensitivity etc.
{
//pretty complicated sorting code that uses cmp.Compare(string1, string2)
}
public void SortStrings()
{
//equally complicated sorting code that uses string.CompareTo()
}
```

We have:

```
public void SortStrings(IComparer<string> cmp)//lets caller decide about case-sensitivity etc.
{
//pretty complicated sorting code that uses cmp.Compare(string1, string2)
}
public void SortStrings()
{
  SortStrings(Comparer<string>.Default);//simple one-line code to re-use all the above.
}
```

As you can see, we've the best of both worlds here. Someone who just wants the default behaviour calls `SortStrings()`, someone who wants a more specific comparison rule to be used calls e.g.  `SortStrings(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`, and the implementation only had to do a tiny bit of work to offer that choice.

This is what is done with the suggestion for `Range` here. The constructor always takes an `IComparer<T>` and always uses it's `Compare`, but there's a factory method that calls it with `Comparer<T>.Default` to offer the other behaviour.

Note that we don't strictly need this factory method, we can just use an overload on the constructor:

```
public Range(T lower, T upper)
  :this(lower, upper, Comparer<T>.Default)
{
}
```

The downside though, is that we can't add a `where` clause to this to restrict it to cases where it'll work. This means that if we called it with types that didn't implement `IComparer<T>` we'd get an `ArgumentException` at runtime rather than a compiler error. Which was Jon's point when he said:

> On the other hand, it does mean that you won't catch incomparable types at compile time.

The use of the factory method is purely to ensure this wouldn't happen. Personally, I'd probably just go with the constructor override and try to be sure not to call it inappropriately, but I added the bit with the factory method since it does combine two things that had come up on this thread.

*Strictly, there's nothing to stop e.g. `A : IComparable<B>`, but while this is of little use in the first place, one also doesn't know for most uses whether the code using it will end up calling `a.CompareTo(b)` or `b.CompareTo(a)` so it doesn't work unless we do the same on both classes. In sort, if it can't be pushed up to a common base-class it's just going to get messy fast.

Comment: I'm a C# novice who is at the momement am digesting your code and addressing the syntax errors. The CompareTo (not Compare) function takes 1 arg. IComparer is IComparable. :-) :-)

Comment: I don't use `CompareTo`, I use `Compare` and `IComparer<T>` and `IComparable<T>` are two different interfaces used in two different ways. The above compiles. I'll add some more info on `IComparer<T>` and `IComparable<T>` to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could use

```
where T : IComparable<T>
```

... or you could just use an [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) in your code, defaulting to [`Comparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx).

This latter approach is useful as it allows ranges to be specified even for types which aren't *naturally* comparable to each other, but could be compared in a custom, sensible way.

On the other hand, it does mean that you won't catch incomparable types *at compile time*.

(As an aside, creating a range type introduces a bunch of interesting API decisions around whether you allow reversed ranges, how you step over them, etc. Been there, done that, was never *entirely* happy with the results...)

Comment: +1 I agree. Better approach is to provide a constructor overload which accepts an `IComparer<T>`, or use `Comparer<T>.Default` if not specified. Restricting the generic type parameter is unnecessary.

Comment: You can get the latter with compile-type safety through a factory method.

Comment: Actually, might as well add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot constrain a T to support a given set of operators, but you can constrain to `IComparable<T>`

```
where T : IComparable<T>
```

Which at least allows you to use `first.CompareTo(second)`. Your basic numeric types, plus strings, DateTimes, etc., implement this interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IComparable` interface which is used widely in the .NET framework.